# Prove that if there is a linear transformation $T(h)$ such that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-T(h)}{h}=0$, then $f'(x_0)$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, derivatives, proof-writing, linear-transformations

I'm trying to prove that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if there is a linear transformation $T(h)$ such that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-T(h)}{h}=0$$
where $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ exists.

In a nutshell I'm trying to prove that the more general definition of differentiability for higher dimensions is an extension of the usual definition of differentiability for functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

---

I have been able to prove that if $f$ is differentiable, then such a linear transformation exists by $$T(h)=f'(x_0)h$$ but I can't seem to prove the other direction.

Comment: You have me confused. Isn't that the definition of differentiability? May you clarify your definition ?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the question.

Comment: Hm, but you see. For any  $T$ , there is a $\lambda$ such that $T(h)=\lambda h$ , then the existence of your intial limit reverts to the usual definition of derivative.

Comment: ah yes, I see it now. Thanks